# How to not use canvas clearRect() for multiple drawings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to do multiple drawings on an image using canvas.

In my code, I use `ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);`
therefore, it does not allow me to do multiple drawings. If I did not use `clearRect()`, the program does not work correctly. Also, I've tried to change the place of `clearRect()`, but it also did not work for me.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas
ctx.beginPath();
var width = mousex-last_mousex;
var height = mousey-last_mousey;
ctx.rect(last_mousex,last_mousey,width,height);
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();
```

```js
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  if (mousedown) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    var width = mousex - last_mousex;
    var height = mousey - last_mousey;
    ctx.rect(last_mousex, last_mousey, width, height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  //Output
  $('#output').html('current: ' + mousex + ', ' + mousey + '<br/>last: ' + last_mousex + ', ' + last_mousey + '<br/>mousedown: ' + mousedown);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-image: url("kroki2v3.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js" integrity="sha256-goy7ystDD5xbXSf+kwL4eV6zOPJCEBD1FBiCElIm+U8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="3200" height="1400"></canvas>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store each rectangle position and size in array and print by looping.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas
ctx.beginPath();
var width = mousex-last_mousex;
var height = mousey-last_mousey;
ctx.rect(last_mousex,last_mousey,width,height);
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = 0;
var last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = 0; 
var mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;
var shapes = [];
var width;
var height;
//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  const lastPos = {
   lastMouseX : last_mousex,
   lastMouseY : last_mousey,
   rectWidth : width,
   rectHeight : height
  }
  shapes.push(lastPos);
  mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  if (mousedown) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    width = mousex - last_mousex;
    height = mousey - last_mousey;
    if (shapes.length > 0){
     for(var i in shapes){
      ctx.rect(shapes[i].lastMouseX, shapes[i].lastMouseY, shapes[i].rectWidth, shapes[i].rectHeight);
     }
    }
    ctx.rect(last_mousex, last_mousey, width, height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  //Output
  $('#output').html('current: ' + mousex + ', ' + mousey + '<br/>last: ' + last_mousex + ', ' + last_mousey + '<br/>mousedown: ' + mousedown);
});
});
```

```css
canvas {
 cursor: crosshair;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 background-image: url("kroki2v3.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="3200" height="1400"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great response. The push() method did not come to my mind.